# Break tag in ngfor loop

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, web-frontend

So i'm trying to have a feature in my angular 9 and bootstrap project listing product cards from a database my problem is that the space between the cards is too small if they go on separate lines
here's my code:

```
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="card-deck">
      <div *ngIf="product.for_sale === 1" class="card" style="width: 18rem; text-align: center;">
        <img id="productimg" class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text"> £{{product.price}}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use margin on the card.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try ngStyle directive. With this you can change a component style in run time with the condition you want. So for example if your component breaks the line, using 'ngStyle' directive you can make a condition to insert a bigger width if this condition is true, and so goes on.

Example:

```
<div *ngIf="product.for_sale === 1" class="card" [ngStyle]="{width: condition ? '18rem' : '20rem'}">
        <img id="productimg" class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text"> £{{product.price}}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```